# Continuous integration with microcontrollers

Tags: windows, jenkins, microcontroller

Just learning about CI and [jenkins](https://jenkins-ci.org/) and wanted to take this concept to the embedded (basically microcontroller) world.  The first step is just making sure builds don't break, but then I realized, I don't have a way to execute a build from a shell script on a linux machine (ubuntu server) for a build that usually happens with an IDE on a windows 7 VM.  How can I automate opening up a Windows 7 VM and then building an [MPLABX](http://www.microchip.com/pagehandler/en-us/family/mplabx/) project for example.

Answer (score 4):

I'm doing the same thing; a Jenkins server running on Ubuntu, and builds need to happen on Windows with some toolchains that don't always work well for automated builds (IAR in my case).

You can set up a Windows machine/VM with the right tools (incl. Java and git or whatever SCM you use), and install a Jenkins slave agent on it (see https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Step+by+step+guide+to+set+up+master+and+slave+machines).

Connect it to the Jenkins server as node/slave.

Now create a job that uses the "Windows batch command" build step. Your IDE probably has some way to build a project from command line.

Add a post-build step to archive artifacts, i.e. the built files you care about.

Answer (score 0):

-> You can connect your Windows VM as jenkins node and activate Jenkins as service in it.

-> Try to build or run your project from command line. (windows cmd prompt)

-> If your tool has own prompt then invoke your prompt by using normal windows prompt and use.

-> After this you can run your commands in Jenkins using "Windows batch command"

Comment: From the question it seems that the asker wants to run the build on ubuntu.

Comment: Asker wants to use Windows 7 VM

Comment: So instead of adding linux server as jenkins node ,It should be better to add Windows VM as jenkins node